# Grails adding to a function's return values before returning them

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a function (the caller) that returns certain values. Before they are returned, they are added to by the result of calling another function (the callee), is there a neater way to add the callee function's resultant values to the caller function's resultant values before the are returned?

```
def funcA() { // Caller Function
   def a,b,c
   a = blah
   b = blah blah
   ...
   def (d,e) = funcB()
   a += d // Is there a neater way to encapsulate 
   b += e // these additions somehow into the previous line? maybe kind of like
          // (a,b) += funcB() ?
   return [a,b,c]
}

def funcB() { // Callee Function
   def d,e
   ...
   return [d,e]
}
```

Comment: provided that funcB always returns a collection you can simply use `plus` to combine the two collections. e.g. `return ([a] + funcB())`

Comment: @JoshuaMoore But funcB is returning two values, so which one is added to a by your syntax?

Comment: In my example it would take both collections and combine the elements to provide a new collection. `[1, 2, 3] == ([1] + [2, 3])`

Comment: without knowing the context of your method calls, we can offer you only some basic list operations

Answer (score 0):

to bad we don't have a `zip`, then something like `[a,b].zip()*.sum()` would work.

`transpose()` only gives you the pairs (not the remainder).  so this only works, if your lists are the same length:

```
assert [43,668]==[[1,2,3],[42,666]].transpose()*.sum()
```

One could attempt to fill shorter list with zeros in this case, so the sum is not influenced (at that point this depends on the type there).

So this function is a workaround:

```
def zipadd(a,b) {
    def l = [a,b]
    // iterate over the size of the longer of the two lists
    (0..(l*.size().max()-1)).collect{
        // get the pairs, filter null, sum both
        l*.getAt(it).findAll{it!=null}.sum()
    }
}

assert [43,668,3]==zipadd([1,2,3],[42,666])
assert [43,668,3]==zipadd([42,666],[1,2,3])
assert [24,93,0,1]==zipadd([1,0,0,1], [23,93])
```

If you use pass l directly (a list of lists) instead of a and b this should also work with more than two elements.